# How can I find the physical path of wwwroot, in a Blazor app razor page without a controller?

Tags: blazor-server-side

i am trying to use the following code in a page in my blazor app ( blazor server app)

@inject IWebHostEnvironment WebhostEnvironment

```
public IWebHostEnvironment _environment { get; set; }


   var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    //string uploads = @"z:\Downloads";


                path = uploads + "\\"  + file.FileInfo.Name;
                FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                file.Stream.WriteTo(filestream);
                filestream.Close();
                file.Stream.Close();
```

to get files to save in an uploads folder within the wwwroot folder but when I execute the code I get ' object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Questions
1.what is causing the error?
2.Is saving uploads in wwwroot subfolder the best route to go?
3. In a network server environment could a network path simply be set in a string variable as an alternative? When I uncomment the string uploads line above the upload is successful to the designated network drive on my home network.

Thanks for whatever information can be provided...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume we speak about "Blazor server-side".

The physical wwwroot folder may be found by:

```
string rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
```

Saving uploaded files to a sub-dir of wwwroot is sometimes not optimal, as for security reasons, this place has to be read-only. Do your users need to download back uploaded files? If not, a temp folder outside the wwwroot will be a better place.

Network path? It's possible, but your web-application should run under credentials with read-write permissions on this place. Normally, web-applications run with restricted credentials.

In conclusion: your 2 last questions must be seen regarding security concerns.

Comment: The problem with using `GetCurrentDirectory` is that it may not always return what you want, as the current directory can be modified (by your own code or some library you're using). It's safer to use `CurrentDomain`.

Answer (score 5):

The current solution didn't work for me as I'm using Blazor wasm.
The physical pathcan be found by accessing the AppDomain or AppContext:

```
string rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");
```

To access both you can use :

```
var b = $"Physical location {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}";
var c = $"AppContext.BaseDir {AppContext.BaseDirectory}";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Blazor Server) I include this statement in my OnInitialized method:

rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");

rootpath is a private variable in the code block.

Then I use this approach to determine if I'm in debug mode (I work off the X: drive).  The idea is, I want my code to work when I'm debugging or if the page is uploaded to the website.

```
    if (rootpath.Contains("X:\\"))
    {
        rootpath = rootpath.Replace("bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\", "");
    }
    
    imagefullpath = rootpath + "\\Images\\Site\\AQ16.PNG";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about Debugger.IsAttached https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=net-7.0